# Android studio does not launch first try sometimes

Tags: java, android

When I change the code and try to lauch the app sometimes this happends:

```
Installing ...
Success


Launching application: ...
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: ...
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
at com.htc.customization.HtcCustomizationManager.<init>(HtcCustomizationManager.java:65)
at com.htc.customization.HtcCustomizationManager.<clinit>(HtcCustomizationManager.java:60)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.getCustomizationReader(Environment.java:523)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.isDynamicSwitchSupported(Environment.java:534)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.<init>(Environment.java:222)
at android.os.Environment.initForCurrentUser(Environment.java:142)
at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:136)
at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:726)
at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:215)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:106)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted
```

And the app does not lauch unless I rebuild the solution - then it launches fine

This is not that serious but very annoying as it happens once every 3-4 builds

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have and HTC phone (M8 I'd guess) with HTC Sense. There is a bug in their code which prevents you from installing the app sometimes. Here's relevant question and answer from [HTCdev FAQ](https://www.htcdev.com/resources/faq):

> **Why does my debug APK sometimes fail to install or run on my device
>   and how to recover?**
>
> HTC devices with Lollipop 5.0.0 or 5.0.1 may experience this issue and
>   we suggest retrying the installation step for workaround. HTC will
>   prepare the solution to address the issue on Lollipop MR1.

So, nothing you can do but to wait for Android update. Since HTC backed off from pushing Lollipop MR1, you will have to wait for Marshmallow update.

Comment: I have HTC One m7. Thanks for the info

Comment: I seem to have the same annoying problem with a cheap 10 inch Insignia tablet I purchased from Best Buy (Target device: tianshi_digi_land-ns_p10a6100 5.0.1).